# Can conference papers use the original words in published papers?

Tags: publications, computer-science, writing

Conference papers are often only about 10 pages. When I was writing conference papers, some words seemed unnatural. Can I directly use the original words in someone else's paper? Not a conclusion or opinion. For example:

> In this paper, we investigate and present a new type of hardware vulnerability to covert timing channels exposed by [Other people's methods]

I changed it to mine in the thesis:

> In this paper, we investigate and present a new type of hardware vulnerability to covert timing channels exposed by others + [my method]

Is this feasible? I just used its sentences to express my idea

Comment: How much of your exposition is taken from this paper (possibly with minor word/grammar changes)? One sentence, or several paragraphs? If that's substantial, it's a whole different business.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can. Some sentences will inevitably be the same in multiple papers. This is, in my eyes, not necessarily plagiarism. Plagiarism is taking "someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own". What you are doing here is taking somebody else's words that describe work or ideas and passing them off as your own.

That said, in a case like this there is absolutely no reason why you shouldn't just change the sentence to avoid any perception of plagiarism. For example:

> Past methods have exposed a new type of hardware vulnerability to covert timing channels [REFs]. Using 'my method' we investigated such vulnerabilities and present them in this work.

Comment: +1 Your revision also fixes a word order concern that (at least for me) caused an unnecessary pause in thought, namely "*we investigate and present*". The pause was to wonder whether the seemingly incorrect temporal order -- investigate followed by present -- was a wording oversight or something specific about the nature of the topic (of which I know know nothing about). Although your word order is the same, we now have "investigated" and "present" applying to different things.